# Does USMT 5.0 require the HOST to see the Domain Controller and on the network?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, migration, windows-domain, migration-assistant

I am scripting up a semi-automate migration process of 32bit Win XP user profiles/app settings/document to new 64 bit Windows 7 boxes using the **USMT 5.0 tools (latest).**

I know all about the exclude and include user rules:

```
/ue:*\* 
/ui:DOMAIN\username
```

I am having some good test results with LOCAL HOST users in limited tests of my scripts.. BUT.. have a problem when the Source HOST is NOT plugged into the Domain network for when I want to scan and migrate DOMAIN\userids  .. the HOST is a fully activated Domain Computer.. its just not plugged into the network when doing the **scanstate.exe** process

According to the MSFT Docs.. BOTH Scanstate and LoadState **DO NOT** need to be "physically wired" to the domain network in order to migrate Domain\Users?  but my test's show otherwise.

**.. my scan process NEVER seems to include TC\username **
where "TC" is the domain name.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825093.aspx

You can gather domain accounts without the source computer having domain controller access. This functionality is available without any additional configuration.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825190.aspx

LoadState does not require domain controller access to apply domain profiles. This functionality is available without any additional configuration. It is not necessary for the source computer to have had domain controller access when the user profile was gathered using ScanState. However, domain profiles are inaccessible until the destination computer is joined to the domain.

Here is my complete scan state line
!! NOTE: my store path IS valid.. no errors from that.
!! Note: my xml input files are just the USMT ones that everyone starts with; NOT changed!
!! The select DOMAIN user to scan and store for this HOST is TC\patenar
!! but TC\patenar is NOT backed up in the store files!!!

```
    scanstate.exe ^
    %g_userstore% ^
    /nocompress ^
    /targetWindows7 ^
    /o ^
    /v:13 ^
    /l:%g_userstore%\log_scanstate.log ^
    /listfiles:%g_userstore%\log_listfiles.log ^
    /progress:%g_userstore%\log_scan_progress.log ^
    /i:..\miguser.xml ^
    /i:..\migdocs.xml ^
    /i:..\migapp.xml ^
    /i:..\exclude.xml ^
    /localonly ^
    /ue:*\* ^
    /ui:TC\%_username%
```

** the scan log file shows the params passed **

```
2014-02-06 16:01:55, Info                  [0x000000] SCANSTATE.EXE Version 6.2.9200.16384[gle=0x000000b7]
2014-02-06 16:01:55, Info                  [0x000000] USMT Started at 2014/02/06:16:01:55.563
2014-02-06 16:01:55, Info                  [0x000000] Command line: scanstate.exe \tc\mig\store\patenar /nocompress /targetWindows7 /o /v:13 /l:\tc\mig\store\patenar\log_scanstate.log /listfiles:\tc\mig\store\patenar\log_listfiles.log /progress:\tc\mig\store\patenar\log_scan_progress.log /i:..\tc-miguser.xml /i:..\tc-migdocs.xml /i:..\tc-migapp.xml /i:..\tc-exclude.xml /localonly /ue:*\* /ui:TC\patenar

                                   Computer name: PNRWPGNBW716479
                               Machine SID: S-1-5-21-200290281-3051264206-3464943771
                               OS version: 5.1.2600.Service Pack 3
                               Language: en-US
                               Architecture: 32-bit

                               Drives:
                                 C: Type: Fixed, Bus type: SCSI, Hotplug: No
                                 D: Type: CD/DVD
                                 A: Type: Removable
                                 Z: Type: Remote

                               Users:
                                 PNRWPGNBW716479\SUPPORT_388945a0, administrator: No, interactive: No, logged on: No, has profile: No
                                 pnrbue, administrator: Yes, interactive: Yes, logged on: No, has profile: Yes
                                 PNRWPGNBW716479\HelpAssistant, administrator: No, interactive: No, logged on: No, has profile: No
                                 mitenkb, administrator: No, interactive: Yes, logged on: No, has profile: Yes
                                 PNRWPGNBW716479\EddieED, administrator: Yes, interactive: Yes, logged on: Yes, has profile: Yes
                                 fernandez, administrator: Yes, interactive: Yes, logged on: No, has profile: Yes
                                 saigon, administrator: Yes, interactive: Yes, logged on: No, has profile: Yes
                                 patenar, administrator: No, interactive: Yes, logged on: No, has profile: Yes
                                 tatu, administrator: No, interactive: Yes, logged on: No, has profile: Yes
                                 mmarky, administrator: Yes, interactive: Yes, logged on: No, has profile: Yes
                                 COUNTZERO, administrator: Yes, interactive: Yes, logged on: No, has profile: Yes
                                 PNRWPGNBW716479\Guest, administrator: No, interactive: Yes, logged on: No, has profile: No
                                 PNRWPGNBW716479\ASPNET, administrator: No, interactive: No, logged on: No, has profile: No
                                 Chukles, administrator: Yes, interactive: Yes, logged on: No, has profile: Yes
                                 PNRWPGNBW716479\___VMware_Conv_SA___, administrator: No, interactive: No, logged on: No, has profile: No
                                 farhats, administrator: No, interactive: Yes, logged on: No, has profile: Yes
```

and the input/out from my script leading up to the scan process

```
    @@@ the users on this host are:

Administrator
All Users
Chukles
COUNTZERO
farhats
fernandez
log
mitenkb
mmarky
patenar
pnrbue
saigon
scripts
tatu
TEMP

@@@ asking for username
Enter a valid username to SCAN and store: patenar

@@@ Username provided was [patenar]
Press any key to continue . . .

@@@ creating migration store paths

user store path= "\tc\mig\store"\patenar

enter::scan_state

SCANSTATE.EXE Version 6.2.9200.16384
(C) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Log messages are being sent to 'Z:\tc\mig\store\patenar\log_scanstate.log'

Starting the migration process
Processing the settings store

Examining the system to discover the migration units
 This Computer (1 of 1): 100% done

Selecting migration units

Estimating total file size for the progress log
 S-1-5-21-85988526-1538548721-1197542801-29154 - 0 files
 S-1-5-21-85988526-1538548721-1197542801-15066 - 0 files
 PNRWPGNBW716479\EddieED - 0 files
 S-1-5-21-85988526-1538548721-1197542801-8188 - 0 files
 S-1-5-21-85988526-1538548721-1197542801-70694 - 0 files
 S-1-5-21-85988526-1538548721-1197542801-68112 - 0 files
 S-1-5-21-85988526-1538548721-1197542801-49517 - 0 files
 S-1-5-21-85988526-1538548721-1197542801-97899 - 0 files
 S-1-5-21-85988526-1538548721-1197542801-8194 - 0 files
 S-1-5-21-85988526-1538548721-1197542801-97933 - 0 files
 S-1-5-21-85988526-1538548721-1197542801-37315 - 0 files
 This Computer - 14879 files

Gathering data
 This Computer (1 of 1): 100% done
 Commit

Success.

ScanState return code: 0

@@@@ COMPLETED: scan of [] to ["\tc\mig\store"\patenar]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the very subtle reason WHY my Domain Users can't be resolved and found during scan state process... even though the Official Microsoft Docs says that the computer does NOT need to be connected to the domain network in order to backup or filter on domain users.....

... what the Microsot docs DO NOT TELL you is that IF the machine has been "removed from the Domain" on the domain controller.. then even though the Domain user profiles still exist on the computer.. the system has NO WAY of resolving which domain they belong to.. so you can only do one type of scan and load operation with DOMAIN USERS.. that is INCLUDE ALL of the Domain Users in the data store.. and RESTORE them all in the LOAD process... no way to filter out a single DOMAIN USER since the /ui:\ will never work.

If you Add the computer name back to the Domain Controller.. and connect the computer to the network again.. then scan state can RESOLVE the Domain name in the /ue: and /ue: parameters.

Proof of this is in the following image from a windows XP machine that has lots of Domain account profiles on it.. but has been REMOVED from the Domain the last time it was on the network.

[image]